# Rewriting conditionals in OOP without generics

Tags: conditions, factory

Let's say I have a set of objects,

```
foo f;
bar br;
baz bz;
```

I also have a string of JSON data,

```
string JSONstring;
```

Depending on the object type of the JSON string, I need to transform it into either foo, bar, or baz. Ok, cool, I'll have a method for that.

```
public object parseJSONToFooBarBaz(string jsonString);
```

What I want to avoid is writing something like:

```
map<string, object> topLevelJSON = deserialized json string;

if(map[foo] != null) return new foo(jsonString);
else if(map[bar] != null) return new bar(jsonString);
...
// And the list balloons up and is difficult to maintain
```

I feel like this is either a good condidate or almost a good candidate for a factory pattern, but something doesn't feel quite right. Is there a simple solution that I'm overlooking, or is a set of conditionals or a switch/case really an OK way to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to write a "generic" JSON mapper that can convert any JSON object to any object within your application without knowing the object type contained within the JSON?

Comment: Not quite, there is some extra logic involved in the mapping that needs to be coded. For example, the JSON field might be "system_id", and it maps to "foo_id" in the foo object but "external_id" in the bar object, and "system_id" in baz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to make a `map<string, string -> object)` where `string -> object` just means a function taking a `string` and producing an `object`.  If the language you are using doesn't support first-class functions you can use the Strategy pattern.  The Factory pattern is essentially just a special case of the Strategy pattern and thus just a round-about way of doing first-class functions (though the term "Factory" communicates intent.)

You could then do something like:

```
foreach(key in factories.keys()) {
    if(topLevelJSON[key] != null) {
        return factories[key](jsonString);
    }
}
```

I assume these keys are mutually exclusive (as suggested by your if statements), though you could easily adapt the code to return all the choices or have a list of the factories in priority order.